# Can't figure out promises with mongod and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a function getStuff() that needs to return the results of a query against MongoDB.  I'm using nodejs and the mongod module.  Here's the code I've got.

```
var mongo = require("mongod");
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/my-mongo";

function getStuff() {
    var db = new mongo(url, ["stuff"]);
    var promise = db.stuff.find()
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        });
    console.log(promise);
    return promise;
}

exports.getStuff = getStuff;
```

I'm obviously missing something about how promises work. I'm getting good data in the first two console.log() calls.  However the getStuff() function always returns undefined.  This seems like it should be a super simple use case but I'm banging my head on my desk trying to get it to work properly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...that needs to return the results...

to get the data from `getStuff`

```
function getStuff(callback) {
    var db = new mongo(url, ["stuff"]);
    db.stuff.find()
    .done(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            callback(result);
     }));
}
```

then you can call it like this

```
getStuff(function(data){
//here you will get your results
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  This gets the job done.  I'll continue playing with it.  I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Your last log and return statement run as your `.find.then.done` chain are still being executed (that's Async for ya!). That's why `promise` is still `undefined`.

Try returning the entire promise, like instead of
`var promise = db.stuff.find()...`
try
`return db.stuff.find()...`

Comment: This has the same problem as my original code.  It returns an undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Daniel.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Actually, on further review of the situation, you can do what you were saying here, Daniel.  I had terminated my .then() chains with the .done() on the return statement.  That was causing it to mess up.  If I left the .done() call off it returned the promise from the last .then() call.

I'm still not sure which implementation is going to work best for me at this point.  I'd upvote your answer but I don't have the rep yet to do so.

Comment: No problem! I'm glad you found a way (two!) to fix your problem. Feel free to update somehow if you learn more about how to use promises here. (edit question, new question linked in comments, etc)